# Unable to get hidden option at the starting of the program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to hide the div element when the program is started and when in that program i click a button (Change Log) it should show the Div element.
I want to hide the div element at first and when a button is clicked it should show the div element.

```
function ChangeLog(){

       if (document.getElementById('divChangeLog').style.display === 
            "none")
      {
         document.getElementById('divChangeLog').style.display = "block";
    }
      else {
        document.getElementById('divChangeLog').style.display = "none";
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok just using js (jQuery) start by hiding the element with `.hide()` (or `.toggle(false)` ) then toggle visibility with `.toggle()` on button click.

```js
const $changeLog = $('#divChangeLog');
$changeLog.hide();
const $button = $('#change');
$button.click(function() {
  $changeLog.toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="change">Change visibility</button>
<div id="divChangeLog">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the element to have a CSS class that hides it. This will take
   care of it being hidden when the page first loads.
2. In the `click` event callback of a `button`, toggle that CSS class
   to reveal or re-hide the element.

FYI: Don't use inline styles if you can help it. It makes the CSS harder to override if needed. Instead, use pre-made CSS classes and just add, remove, or toggle them as needed.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button");     // Get reference to button
let div = document.querySelector("div.hidden"); // Get reference to hidden div

// Set up click event on button
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  div.classList.toggle("hidden"); // Toggle CSS
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div><button>Click to Toggle</button></div>
<div class="hidden">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: I am using javascript so i cant use .hidden{display:none;}

Comment: @Z7272727 I don't understand what you mean.Just add the CSS class.

Comment: My file is .js and it has javascript, html and jquery in a single file. I am not sure how to add css class in it. When i am adding . hidden line in my code it's giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function changeLog() {
  let changeLogDiv = document.getElementById("changeLogDiv")
  if (changeLogDiv.className === "hide") {
    changeLogDiv.className = "show"
  } else {
    changeLogDiv.className = "hide"
  }
}

document.getElementById("showHideButton").addEventListener("click", changeLog)
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="showHideButton">show/hide</button>
<div id="changeLogDiv" class="hide">Hello, World!</div>
```

It starts with the div hidden then shows and hides it when a button is pressed.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Yes, but i want it to hide first and then when it is clicked show

Comment: @Z7272727 It should do that.

Comment: You really shouldn't use inline CSS or inline HTML event attributes. There are tons of reasons why. It's 2019.

Comment: $("#divChangeLog").html($ChangeTable); This is how i am calling my div in my javascript . How to put style in this?

Comment: @Z7272727 That is JQuery syntax. Please update your question to show all the relevant code and add the appropriate tags. Also, explain why you can't simply define a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
function ChangeLog(){
   if($('#changeLogDiv:visible').length == 0)
   {
       $('#changeLogDiv').show();
   }else{
       $('#changeLogDiv').hide();
   }
}
```